# excel VBA IE droplist selection

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer, vba

I have a problem choosing item from dropdown list in IE. All items are with tag "list".

```
<div class="btn-grp-search">
  <input name="1_0" tabindex="0" class="..." role="combobox" aria-labelledby="QueryComboBox_Label">
  <span></span>
   <ul tabindex="0" class="..." id="id-999" role="combobox">
    <li tabindex="-1" class="menu-item" id="id-223" data-lovtype="Blah List Applet:QueryComboBox" data-licval="">Number</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="menu-item" id="id-224" data-lovtype="Blah List Applet:QueryComboBox" data-licval="">Other</li>
```

My **not** working solutions so far are by searching ID of list item:

```
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("li")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
   If objCollection(i).ID = "id-223" Then
        objCollection(i).Select
        i = objCollection.Length
   End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

and by searshing for the combobox ID

```
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("ul")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
   If objCollection(i).ID = "id-999" Then
       li.Value = "Number"
       i = objCollection.Length
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

This structure of the searches works for other content in the web page like fill-in boxes, etc., but for the drop it just can't select the item.

Comment: Would you be able to share the URL?

Comment: Sorry Xabier, it is password protected. If you need more html, I can copy.

Comment: I'm gonna say something maybe stupid, but could you try with `objCollection.InnerText` ?? Maybe trying to identify the option `Number` or the option `Other`. This once worked for me in the past.

Comment: The combobox doesn't seem to be an actual HTML input. In the web browser change the drop-down selection and see what changes in the HTML, then try to mick that in your code. For example, if it adds attributes then try to add attributes within your code. It might actually change the class when you change selection.